# Consuming a WCF service from Javascript - getting HTTP 400 on requests for jsdebug

Tags: wcf, javascript-debugger

I'm trying to create a simple JavaScript test front-end for my WCF service, but the front-end isn't working.  I've traced the problem back to where the web page asks the service for http://..../myservice.svc/jsdebug (which, as I understand it, returns the JavaScript code for the proxy client that the web page can use to access the service) - this request is returning HTTP 400 -Bad Request.

In an effort to reduce the problem to its essentials, I've found I can replicate the problem simply:

- Open Visual Studio 2010
- Create a new project of 
  type WCF Service Application
- Build
- Run
- In a browser navigate to  http://localhost:portnumber/Service1.svc/jsdebug

The result is that the server returns HTTP 400 - Bad Request

What's going on here?

UPDATE:
The .svc file in is:

`<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WebDataProxy.WebDataProxy" CodeBehind="WebDataProxy.svc.cs" %>`

The service interface looks like:

```
namespace WebDataProxy
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://example.com/WebDataProxy")]
    public interface IWebDataProxy
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<DataResponse> GetDataEx(List<DataRequest> requests);

        [OperationContract]
        DataResponse GetDataTest(DataRequest request);

        [OperationContract]
        string Hello(string input);
    }
}
```

Comment: hey dont forget to accept answer if the solution work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can check this post will help you

Article is about calling cross domain wcf service but it also works for same domain

http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2011/06/calling-cross-domain-wcf-service-using.html

Comment: Aha! Interesting, thanks.  It appears that the problem is solved by adding `Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory"`to the .svc file